# Basic C++ Redefinition Error

Tags: c++

I've been reading about header guards and and their use to solve redefinition errors, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it properly. Here's an simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

**fileA.h**

```
#include first_header.h
#include second_header.h

// code here
```

**fileB.h**

```
#include first_header.h
#include second_header.h

// code here
```

**mainfile.cpp**

```
#include fileA.h
#include fileB.h

// code here
```

Now the problem comes in the mainfile.cpp since I need to include both the fileA.h and fileB.h headers, but each of these contains the same header references thus giving me the redefinition error. I'm not really sure how to get around it or implement the header guards properly in this scenario.

Comment: You could use preprocessor statements like #ifndef for if not defined.

Comment: If `first_header.h` and `second_header.h` have include guards, there should be no problem.  In the `mainfile.cpp`, the compiler will open up `fileB.h` then open `first_header.h`, realize that the include header definition is defined and ignore everything in the file.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] . You have not shown first_header.h nor second_header.h  nor stated that they have (or not) their own guards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to put either quotes or angle brackets around the filenames, like this:
`#include <fileA.h>`
or
`#include "fileA.h"`

From what you've posted, it looks like you don't really understand how header guards work. So here's the rundown.

Let's say I have a function that I want to be able to call from different c++ files. You first need a header file. (You can do includes from inside your include guard.)

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_HPP
#define MYHEADER_HPP

#include "first_header.h"
#include "second_header.h"

void MyFunction();

#endif
```

The non-include preprocessor lines make up what is called an "Include Guard," and you should always guard your header files.

You then implement said function in a .cpp file, like this:

```
#include "MyHeader.hpp"

void MyFunction()
{
    // Implementation goes here
}
```

Now, you can use this function in other code:

```
#include "MyHeader.hpp"

int main()
{
    MyFunction();
}
```

If you're using an IDE compiling and linking is handled for you, but just in case, you can compile and link like this using g++ (assuming a "main.cpp" file and a "MyFunction.cpp" file):

```
g++ main.cpp -c
g++ MyFunction.cpp -c
g++ main.o MyFunction.o -o MyExecutable
```

I hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you. This was very informative. I'm still quite new to this.

Comment: @alduin Check out this article on cplusplus.com, it's very informative, and where I learned about include guards when I started out programming: [http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/Gw6AC542/](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/Gw6AC542/) Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

**Logic:**
Check if specific macro is defined, if the macro is not defined, define it and include the content of the header file. This will prevent from duplicated inclusion of the header content.

Like this:

file A:

```
#ifndef fileA_h
#define fileA_h

#include first_header.h
#include second_header.h

//code here

#endif
```

file B:

```
#ifndef fileB_h
#define fileB_h

#include first_header.h
#include second_header.h

//code here

#endif
```

Comment: This helped further my understanding of header guards. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers (e.g. Visual Studio) also support **`#pragma once`** which can be used instead of include guards expressed as "#ifndef". You will find that in some legacy code written with MS Visual C++.

However, the

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_HPP
#define MYHEADER_HPP

// code here

#endif
```

is more portable.

Comment: Few problems with this answer. 1. It's more of a comment. 2. #pragma once is an include guard. 3. I can think of several prominent compilers that don't support #pragma once, and the thing with  pragmas is they  are often silently ignored when not supported. Make certain your compiler supports it before investing much in a pragma.

Comment: 1. You are right @user4581301. Completely agree.
2. Just wanted to mention, that "#pragma once" also exists. Because it was not mentioned, yet. It was more to tell the OP what it means if he encounters it in other peoples code than to propose to use it.
3. First wanted to mention it as a comment, but Stackoverflow didn't allow me to write a comment, therefore I put it into an "answer".

Comment: Much more answer-like. I recommend dropping the last line of the first paragraph because it's not legacy. `once` is probably the way of the future, as soon as a few bugs and portability issues are resolved.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn't say "it's legacy", I said it's used more often "in legacy code" (especially in VS code, maybe because MS supported it earlier than e.g. GCC did), that's a difference. What do you mean by "answer-like"? What do you miss? I think the other part of the question is already answered in the other answers, so consider mentioning of "#pragma once" just as an addition.